# iwlwifi error, then WLAN is very slow and can't see other WLANs

Tags: linux, wifi

I have a wireless interface Intel 1030 on a Dell XPS 15 laptop. `lspci` says:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
```

Recently I noticed that the error message `iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues` appears in dmesg, then my WLAN is very slow (to the point that names will fail to resolve 90% of the time). <strike>and I can't connect to any network other than the one I'm currently connected to (both `iwlist wlan0 scan` and NetworkManager or wicd don't show any other networks)</strike> (edit: this last problem was a false alarm)

The only cure is disabling/enabling the wireless network. [Here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152383) I find that it might be related to suspend, however it appears even after a fresh boot or when under heavy traffic (e.g. downloading a torrent).

Forcing the card to use only 802.11g (`11n_disable=1` option when loading the module) helps somewhat.

Any clues? It happens both in Ubuntu 12.10 (kernel 3.5), openSUSE 12.3 (kernel 3.7) and Arch Linux (kernel 3.7.10 or 3.8.2-ck).

Comment: Doesn't help, sadly.

Comment: what is the output of lscpi in reference to the wireless device in question?

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arch Linux **no longer** uses `wlan0` or `eth0` when it comes to naming the wireless devices. The command `ip a` will display the list of devices in a numbered list with their names. The only way that the old network devices names are used is if the device can not supply a suitable name for the device or if you have a `udev` rule in place to point the devices back to their old names. Once you have the device names correct then use those names with iwlist or whatever network manager that you're using.

I'm assuming that you're using Arch Linux since the link you've provided is to the Arch Linux forums.

---

Create  to following file and add the following settings inside of it.

```
/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf (file to be created)
-------------------------------------------------
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Just to be safe, check the `HOOKS=` array inside `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` and make sure that the `modconf` is in the array. If it isn't then add it. You will then have to rebuild the `initramfs` and `reboot`.

If you're unsure on how to rebuild the `initramfs`. `mkinitcpio -p linux`

Comment: If you're trying to use both cards at the same time. Then one of the wireless cards would have to be placed in managed mode, while the other is in monitor mode.

Comment: The problem is distro-agnostic (it happens in all distros I've tried - Ubuntu w/kernel 3.5, Arch Linux w/kernels 3.7 and 3.8 and openSUSE w/kernel 3.7).

Comment: What type of network card are you using? What's the output of lspci in reference to the device?

Comment: updated question with this information

Comment: Create and add the following to /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf 

options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0

Then make sure to check /etc/mkinitcpio.conf and make sure that modconf is added to the HOOKS="" array. If it isn't add it and then rebuild the initramfs and then reboot.

Comment: Adding those options seems to have worked (even if I get the error message, I don't get the slowdown); can you add them to your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're okay with running at g speeds, there are a couple more options you could try:

- `swcrypto=1`
- `wd_disable=1`

I have an Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 with similar issues, and `wd_disable=1` fixes it for me. I don't have to use it with recent kernels though.

Answer (score 1):

I have had slow (iwl)wifi for a long time... Now I had a need for
faster connection and after browsing a while found these instructions

after 2 rounds of trial & error I got

```
$ sudo rmmod iwldvm

$ sudo rmmod iwlwifi 

$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

work for me, in a live situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's related to your wireless options, some of wireless cards have many feature which incompatiable with wake up option. however, if i have your problem, compile a new kernel such as 3.8.2 milestone.

Comment: I have 3.8.3. It still happens there.

Answer (score 0):

[This Ubuntu Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1270808), which points to [this Kernel bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=56581), seems to be about this.