# Wifi Intel 7265 error & disconnecting -- iwlwifi fail to flush all tx fifo queues -- Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: debian, wifi, iwlwifi

I have serious WiFi stability issues on Debian 8 [1] with Intel 7265 WiFi chipset [2]. I randomly loose the internet connection, albeit seemingly retaining the WiFi connection intact. Ad hoc I could regain connection by turning off/on the Wifi, or rebooting the system. Last months things got worse -- lost connection more frequently, <5min --, so I decided to reinstall the OS. Without success :-(

I researched and tried but got no results. I found out [that the chipset lost support for the newest firmware versions](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi?do=#and_7265_support). I've discovered some commands to readout the/some errors [3]. And a possible solution -- which is to cryptic for me to adapt --, to a [seemingly *very similar* problem linked here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67267/iwlwifi-error-then-wlan-is-very-slow-and-cant-see-other-wlans). As well as the there required output [4].

Since I'm using the `non-free` drivers, I thought, maybe I should try the `free` ones instead. Maybe things get better. However I'm afraid I'm to unexperienced to remove the now active faulty drivers, install the open ones, and reconfigure the kernel. But, with some assistance, I would definitively give it a try. Thank you :)

[1] Linux version

```
$ uname -a
Linux XXXXXX 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

[2] Chipset

```
$ lspci | grep Wireless
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 3b)
```

[3] Error output

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[   38.436666] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 65 for MSI/MSI-X
[   38.450545] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
[   38.450870] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 23.214.9.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   38.486339] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x184
[   38.486636] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   38.486798] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   40.220157] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[   40.220323] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled

[  275.958950] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues Q 0

[  275.958958] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Current SW read_ptr 14 write_ptr 15
[  275.958995] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(0) = 0x00000000
[  275.959007] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(1) = 0x80102052
[  275.959019] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(2) = 0x00000000
[  275.959032] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(3) = 0x8030000e
[  275.959044] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(4) = 0x00000000
[  275.959056] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(5) = 0x00000000
[  275.959069] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(6) = 0x00000000
[  275.959082] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FH TRBs(7) = 0x00709082
[  275.959133] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 0 is active and mapped to fifo 3 ra_tid 0x0000 [14,15]
[  275.959183] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 1 is active and mapped to fifo 2 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959233] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 2 is active and mapped to fifo 1 ra_tid 0x0000 [83,83]
[  275.959284] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 3 is active and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959335] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 4 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959385] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 5 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 6 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959485] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 7 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959536] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 8 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959587] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 9 is active and mapped to fifo 7 ra_tid 0x0000 [131,131]
[  275.959637] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 10 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959687] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 11 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959738] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 12 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959788] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 13 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959838] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 14 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959888] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 15 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959938] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 16 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.959988] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 17 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.960038] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 18 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  275.960090] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Q 19 is inactive and mapped to fifo 0 ra_tid 0x0000 [0,0]
[  276.212876] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[ 6230.465289] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[ 6230.466255] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
[ 6230.466413] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled
```

[4] Required output for possible solution

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:65:ec:4b:84:e4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:57:18:17:7d:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.24/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 860308sec preferred_lft 860308sec
    inet6 fe80::6257:18ff:fe17:7d4d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **workaround** I've set the router 5G network with a distinctive name and created a wifi profile on the machine for it. The disconnections stopped!

It seems that the problem is rooted in the SSID management for multiple wifi-stardads by the linux-driver.